Group arrays with same size efficiently
I am trying to group arrays with the same size.
The arrays can be grouped if all of the values (30) within the array are the same, so all values must be the same.
For example: -1.345509 == -1.345509 and this for every of the 30 values in an array.
All values within the array have the same precision.
For this example, I fetch data from a dataframe and use arrays to compare.
Comparing the first and second rows:
sum(np.array(df.iloc[0,:]) == np.array(df.iloc[1,:]) ) == 30

If there's no match (pair) within the set, the array falls into the last group (no match).
I have written some code to group arrays by using combinations:
# I have multiple datasets on which I want to apply the same algorithm.
# Sorted by 'Var1'

dfs = dict(tuple(all_data.groupby('Var1')))
dfs_used = dfs.copy()
dfs_not_used = {k:[] for k,v in dfs.items()}
dfs_used_pair = dfs.copy()

for k,v in dfs.items():
    combi = np.arange(len(dfs[k]))
    combi_all = list(combinations(list(combi),2))
    diff = []
    for i in combi_all:
        plot_x = (i[0])
        plot_y = (i[1])
        f = np.array(dfs[k].iloc[plot_x,:]).astype(float)
        s = np.array(dfs[k].iloc[plot_y,:]).astype(float)
        g = f-s
        euclidean_cal = math.sqrt(sum(g**2))
        max_finger = max(abs(g))
        diff.append([plot_x,plot_y, euclidean_cal,max_finger])
    j = pd.DataFrame(diff)
    j.columns = ['Plot1','Plot2','Euclidean Distance','Max difference per point']
    dfs_copy[k] = j
    check1 = dfs_copy[k][dfs_copy[k]['Euclidean Distance']==0]
    check1_used = list(set(check1['Plot1'])) + list(set(check1['Plot2']))

    last_check = list(set(np.arange(len(dfs[k]))) - set(check1_used))
    #print the rows which cannot be paired to another test.

    if len(last_check)>0:
        dfs_not_used[k] = last_check
    y_dict = dict(tuple(check1.groupby('Plot1')))
    same_groups = y_dict.copy()
    total_used = []
    for d,s in y_dict.items():
        used_now = set(np.array(y_dict[d]['Plot2'])) - set(total_used)
        same_groups[d] = list(used_now)
        total_used.extend(used_now)
    dfs_used_pair[k] = same_groups

And I made a check for all items in the main dictionary:
for k,v in dfs.items():
    total = 0
    for a,b in dfs_used_pair[k].items():
        if len(dfs_used_pair[k][a])>0:
            total += len(dfs_used_pair[k][a])+1
    total += len(dfs_not_used[k])
    print(total==len(dfs[k])) 

This is very time-intensive since it checks every combination of arrays.
Then, my code groups the arrays by the first index of the combination, like:
If (1,2) and (1,3) are the same, then: (1,2,3) is a set.
The code is very simple, but takes a while to run.
What can I do to improve this? And above all, maybe use just a few lines instead of 18 lines which I have now.

I would first make this one liner into separate lines of code and see what takes long. It may be the allocation and not the actual compare operation

Hi, could you please provide the full code that you are using to group arrays. Also some details about your dataframe: how many rows there is in a dataframe?
One of the easiest option would be to sort dataframe by 30 columns. In this case rows that are equal will be groupped together and you only will need to go through the dataframe once.
